# Sudo as different user and running screen

Tags: sudo, gnu-screen

Found out today that running screen as a different user that I sudo into won't work!

i.e.

```
ssh bob@server         # ssh into server as bob
sudo su "monitor" -
screen                 # fails: Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0'
```

I have a script that runs as the "monitor" user. We run it in a screen session in order to see output on the screen. The problem is, we have a number of user who logs in with their own account (i.e. bob, james, susie, etc...) and then they sudo into the "monitor" user. Giving them access to the "monitor" user is out of the question.

Comment: Is this the error that you are getting? "Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/0' - please check."

Comment: yep thats the one. I understand why it's happening but is there a workaround?

Comment: A comment on your commands -- I keep seeing people running `sudo su "user" -`.  Why not use `sudo -u user -s`?

Comment: @Jim: +1 for supplying the missing error message.

Comment: @Andrew Most guys I know do `sudo su` - I think it's just what people get used to (in my case it's because you don't need to know any sudo flags to `sudo su` - I don't think I've ever read the sudo manpage :)

Comment: I had the same issue while trying to run screen from rc.local. Solved it by calling "screen -d -m", even thought I use a configuration file that specifies "detach". Looks like -m makes all the difference, even thought I cannot put it in the configuration file.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Try running `script /dev/null` as the user you `su` to before launching screen - its a ghetto little hack, but it should make screen happy.

Comment: so um ... any security implications with this one? I think I can add the user to the tty group but that wouldn't be ideal. :-P

Comment: Re: security implications, none I'm aware of (but that doesn't mean there aren't any :) - IIRC this relies on a side-effect of "script" opening a new terminal device (as the user invoking it), and since you're sending script's output to /dev/null there's nothing to capture.  It's also definitely safer than adding users to the tty group (IMHO)

Comment: One problem is that it opens another shell I have to exit. It can be confusing. First `sudo su` then `script` then `screen`. Then I have to exit three times.

Comment: @nalply Frankly you shouldn't find multiple shells confusing if you're a Unix system administrator -- that said, `script` can be used to launch `screen`. Then you only have to exit twice (once for `screen`, once for `su`). (This is something the `script` man page can clarify for you, if you take the time to read it...)

Comment: Of course I didn't speak for myself but for colleague. He is not a sysadmin and he just wants his stuff done and then gets out of these three shells as fast as possible. :-)

Comment: Or just run `sudo -u bob script -q -c 'screen -dr myscreen' /dev/null`. Then you only have one terminal to exit/detach from.

Comment: If you want to add this command to the ~/.bashrc of the user, you can add: `[ -n "$SCRIPT" ] || SCRIPT=y script /dev/null
export SCRIPT` This will cause you to have to double exit though.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me. But why does this fix it? From what I understand, it prints everything from stdout to... nowhere. And that somehow fixes screen.

Comment: @sudo In order to do its thing `script` opens its own tty device, owned by the user who ran it (look in `/dev` and you'll see it appear after you run `script`). `screen` then grabs that tty device (which is owned by the user running `screen` so it has no trouble accessing it). It's a total hack job, but it works. Looking at some of my machines it appears new versions of screen seem to install setuid-root, which also works, but means you have another setuid-root binary floating around, which makes some folks justifiably uncomfortable.

Comment: Using `exec` to run either `screen` or `script` will mean you only have to exit once.

Comment: Note that running `script /dev/null` will fail (`script` will immediately exit) if `SHELL` is not set to something reasonable (e.g., to `/bin/false`, for a user not supposed to be allowed to log in). In this case you can do `SHELL=/bin/bash script /dev/null`.

Comment: @voretaq7 but what forbids `screen` itself from doing the same thing as `script` does?

Answer (score 36):

I am using a wrapper function around `screen` for the user(s) that I `sudo su` to. This is the wrapper function that I've added to the user(s) `~/.bashrc`:

```
function screen() {
  /usr/bin/script -q -c "/usr/bin/screen ${*}" /dev/null
}
```

This allows me to use all of the options and parameters for `screen` that I might want to use. I am contemplating on putting this function systemwide.

Comment: Works perfectly. For those wanting this system-wide, I recommend adding this to /etc/bash.bashrc - works across all users.

Comment: This will not quote arguments to screen correctly, otherwise a good solution.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming they are SSHing into the host anyway, you could add the public ssh keys for each user that needs access to the monitor account in the ~monitor/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  Then on each user's remote machine they can run

> ssh -t monitor@remote.machine screen -RD

Comment: This is another good approach -- You would have to specify forced commands in the authorized keys file though (per luckytaxi's "giving them access to the 'monitor' user is out of the question" note above -- forced commands could limit them to just attaching the screen session)

Comment: I wasn't sure how to address that in my answer, because he said "giving them access...is out of the question", but also said "...they sudo into the 'monitor' user".  But I agree, forcing command restriction in the authorized_keys should take care of that.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming we're talking about this error:

```
$ sudo su - bob
$ screen
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/5' - please check.
```

Here's a one-liner (could be used as "alias gobob", for example):

```
sudo su - bob -c "script -c bash /dev/null"'
```

Explanation:

This will start a shell (like login shell) as user bob. User bob starts `script`, which is told to invoke a bash (could be dash or ksh...) and a copy of the session is thrown away.

Answer (score 0):

Probably would have to change permissions on the device in question or add monitor to a group that has permission to read that device, that would be my first inclination. But you'd have to weigh the security implications of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You say you do:

```
sudo su "monitor" -
```

I'm wondering about the trailing dash. I usually do:

```
sudo su - username
```

The dash (per the su man page) tells su to "make the shell a login shell". This means it will source all the usual shell startup scripts and set things like PATH and HOME properly.

Comment: Nope.  `sudo su - username` and `sudo su username -` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I would just give the read/write permission to "other":

```
sudo chmod o+rw /dev/pts/0
```

Then try `screen` again

Answer (score -4):

I just hit this problem. Solved it with `chmod +rw $(tty)` before running sudo.
The problem with this solution is that anyone can connect and snoop on your terminal after that.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It's a great solution, except the part where it gives ***the entire world*** read & write access to his terminal. Just a minor security problem - No program would care about that, except of course anything that checks terminal security before accepting passwords (`gpg` for example). And surely he'll never be on a system with malicious users who would watch the `tty` and sniff passwords...

Comment: **Be warned**: never try this at home! this is dangerous!!!